# Get the Status of the Azure AS via REST API in logic apps

Tags: rest, azure, api, azure-logic-apps, azure-analysis-services

I send a http PATCH request to scale out my Azure AS. (Step 1)

After that I would like to wait until the AzureAS is successfully scaled out and then go to step 2.

[image]

Is it possible to read the status of AzureAS via REST API?

Comment: maybe Get- Server Details has the information you are looking for... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/getdetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could use the [Get details of a serve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/getdetails#get_details_of_a_server)  Rthomas529 mentioned. I test it with postman, it includes ProvisioningState and State.

[image]

From your description, I think what you want is in the logic app add an action to get the `state` then judge whether do the next action. So you could add a HTTP action with GET method to get the server details.

Then use a Compose action to output the HTTP body, next step is get the state value and judge it. You need to go to Code View change the value to `@outputs('Compose')['properties']['state']` and the equal value you could choose the all you could get and the supported state, you could check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/getdetails#state).

[image]

[image]

Then you will be able to add different actions between `If true` and `If false`.
And here is my result.

[image]